# Xamarin forms, make a listview disappear by clicking outside of it

Tags: xamarin

I have a listview that I make visible upon a button press. I want them to disappear if I click anywhere outside of the listview.

How would this be done on Xamarin forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your ListView is inside a StackLayout.
StackLayout can have a TapGestureRecognizer.
Add a TapGestureRecognizer to your StackLayout and when "Tapped" event is rised, set to false the IsVisible's ListView property

Comment: Unfortunetly this closes the listview when you also click "Inside" of it.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple child controls in the StackLayout, Android won't bubble up the gesture from a child view to the parent StackLayout. You can overcome this by placing another stack layout or a box view on top of the rest of the controls using AbsoluteLayout and then adding tap gesture to this box view. And make this box view also disappear along with the list view. Make the color of box view to transparent so that it isn't visible but just sits there to capture gesture.

Answer (score 0):

We could add a Grid as the root layout which has only one row. Make sure the ListView and whatever other layout occupies the same row and this layout has a Tapped Gesture event which controls the visibility attribute of the LiewView.

Answer (score 0):

I did this successfully by creating a full page Frame and placing the ListView inside of it (as a bonus, this gives you easy positioning control of your ListView by setting the Padding on the Frame). Give the Frame an x:Name property, set its BackgroundColor to something semi-transparent or transparent (I used "#33FFFFFF" to subtly show there is an overlay), and add a TapGestureRecognizer to the Frame. Call your PopModalAsync() from the Frame's GestureRecognizer event handler, and voila! Be sure to set your ListView's BackgroundColor to something solid or it will inherit from the Frame's transparency. My code looks like this:

The Modal Popover's XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourProject.YourModalView" BackgroundColor="#00FFFFFF" > <!-- Transparent Page -->
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <Frame x:Name="pageFrame" BorderColor="#332BF37B" BackgroundColor="#33F2FFF7" Padding="80,32" > <!-- Transparent or semi-transparent Frame -->
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnPageFrameTapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <StackLayout>

                <ListView
                x:Name="yourListView" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"> <!-- Solid background for ListView -->
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextCell
                            Text="{Binding Symbol}"
                            Detail="{Binding Name}"
                            DetailColor="#000000"
                            TextColor="#0AAE4B" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

You'll need your GestureRecognizer event handler in your XAML.cs page to dismiss your ModalView...

```
async void OnPageFrameTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}
```

And that should do it. Positioning and sizing your ListView in the full page Frame is as easy as setting the padding on it.